# Performing a function on selected element, and a different function on all other elements of same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of three `<div>` elements, of which one is "selected" on page load (giving it a different colored border). I'm trying to have it such that if a different `<div>` of the same class is clicked, that that particular one receives the new border color while the other two revert to their default grey border.

I have my JS like this:

```
  $('.container').click(function(){
    $(this).css('border','2px solid #ffffff');
    $(this).siblings().css('border','2px solid #e3e3e3');
  });
```

I've also tried using `.not()` with the same result of the code not behaving as expected.

Simplified HTML here:

```
<div class="container">Some Content</div>
<div class="container">Some Content</div>
<div class="container">Some Content</div>
```

The first line works, but the second line doesn't give the element's siblings the different border color. I've looked online but no solutions are giving me what I need. Any help?

Comment: Please show all the relevant code, including the HTML

Comment: Well are they actually siblings?

Comment: @epascarello They don't share the same direct parent but the same parent one level up. If that doesn't count as siblings, I also tried using .not() and I had the same result of the code not behaving as expected.

Comment: Than they are not siblings.... The parents are siblings....So that means the HTML you provided does not match your actual HTML.

Comment: @epascarello Is there then any way to select all elements of a given class regardless of whether they are siblings or not and then remove one of those elements from a function being applied?

Comment: @AKor It doesn't matter what the hierarchy is as long as the "clickable" elements use the same class. See my answer below.

Comment: @epascarello Why does it matter if they are siblings as long as they share a common class?

Comment: @ScottMarcus It matters when the OP is trying to use siblings....

Comment: @epascarello *"I'm trying to have it such that if a different <div> of the same class is clicked, that that particular one receives the new border color while the other two revert to their default grey border."* I don't see any request or requirement that `siblings` be used. I think it's obvious that the OP is just trying anything to make this work.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Dude the comment was on their code.... And that comment was there before the OP had code to support anything. Comments lead to getting answers from people. People on here crack me up and they are concerned about comments that explain why they tried did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you stated that the elements were not siblings, but the parents were. So in that case you would need to select the parent, than siblings, and reselect the containers.

```js
  $('.container').click(function(){
    $(this)
        .css('border','2px solid #ffffff')
        .parent()
           .siblings()
             .find(".container")
               .css('border','2px solid #e3e3e3');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div class="container">Some Content</div></div>
<div><div class="container">Some Content</div></div>
<div><div class="container">Some Content</div></div>
```

In the end that is really strange to do... Other way is to just select the elements, and set a class on the one that is active.

```js
var containers = $('.container');
containers.click(function(){
  containers.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  // If you want to toggle on and off the one that is selected
  // containers.not(this).removeClass("active");
  // $(this).toggleClass("active");

});
```

```css
.container { border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;}
.container.active {  border-color: #ffffff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div class="container">Some Content</div></div>
<div><div class="container">Some Content</div></div>
<div><div class="container">Some Content</div></div>
```

Comment: What am I missing here? This is so overly complicated unnecessarily. As long as the elements in question belong to the same class, which the OP says they do.

Comment: Dude.... The first was showing them what the pattern they were using would need to do and if you read the rest, it shows the better way of doing it. You are on a roll on this one...

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple and doesn't require any particular hierarchy for the elements as long as they are all of the same class.

Just set a default style for that class and add an event handler that resets all the divs to normal but just the one that was clicked to special.

```js
$('.normalDiv').click(function(){
   // First set all div elements back to normal
   $('.normalDiv').removeClass("activeDiv");

   // Then, apply the special class to the clicked div
   $(this).addClass("activeDiv");
});
```

```css
.normalDiv { background-color:#e0e0e0; width:100px;margin:5px; }
.activeDiv { border:1px solid black; background-color:aliceblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="normalDiv">content</div>
  <div>
    <div class="normalDiv">content</div>
    <div class="normalDiv">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```